# rangy - how to work with content in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, rangy

I need your help about rangy library .

How can I apply rangy within iframe selected content, i cant to understand ((

this code in my page create red bold selection with ALL iframe content, but I need to apply it to only user selection

```
var cssApplier;
$("#ok_button").click(function()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_id");
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var range = rangy.createRange(iframeDoc);
    cssApplier.applyToRange(range);
});


$("iframe#iframe_id").load(function()
{
         rangy.init();
    cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("boldRed", {normalize: true});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the selection from the iframe. Here's how:

```
var cssApplier;
$("#ok_button").click(function()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_id");
    var iframeWin = rangy.dom.getIframeWindow(iframe);
    cssApplier.applyToSelection(iframeWin);

    // In Rangy 1.3, you can pass the iframe object directly into
    // applyToSelection so the previous two lines become:
    // cssApplier.applyToSelection(iframe);
});


$("iframe#iframe_id").load(function()
{
         rangy.init();
    cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("boldRed", {normalize: true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Can I wrap my selection by tags, for example "A", "DIV" e.t.c Can I add in some tags within my selection (for example "p") some attributes? Thank you for help

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: I don't really understand what you're getting at. You can set the element tag name to use in the options object passed into `createCssClassApplier()` but I'm not sure what you mean about the attributes, sorry.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, please...`cssApplier = rangy.createCssClassApplier("", { elementTagName: "a", elementProperties: { href: url, target: "_blank" } }); cssApplier.applyToSelection(iframeWin);` this construction create A tag surround my text selection with attribute target=_blank, but not for img within selection. Can I wrap IMG too with my A tag?